# Rails 3: Call back for when a certain object is pulled from the database (Mongo Mapper)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongomapper

I need something that can trigger a method when an object is pull from a database and called. So for instance, let's say I have the class Apple. I preform a query:

```
Apple.where(:name => "Delicious").first
```

which returns

```
#<Apple id: 2, blah, blah, blah>
```

I need a way (call back or other) to call a method so I can keep track of the number of times the item has been pulled from the database. Can anyone suggest a way of doing this? I am using MongoDB with MongoMapper.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's an [after_find](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#after_initialize-and-after_find) callback that gets called after an object is loaded from the database. So:

```
after_find :update_found_count

def found_times
  increment!(:found_count)
end
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution does not work with Mongo Mapper, can you give me a solution catered to that?

Comment: No, sorry, I don't know a fix specific to that. It might be more fruitful to ask a different question though rather than editing this question and potentially making the answers people have already given you irrelevant.

Answer (score 2):

Supposing your model has an attribute called `access_count`, you could override `initialize` to do something like this:

**Update:** [Shadwell's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8971497/179125) is better; direct your upvotes that-a-way. Leaving the below in case it's useful to someone.

```
class Apple < ActiveRecord::Base
  def initialize *args
    super

    incr_access_count
  end

  private
  def incr_access_count
    update_attribute :access_count => access_count + 1 unless new_record?
  end
end
```

This is fairly naive, but predictable anyway. It seems to me that doing this explicitly in your controller would be a much wiser move. Updating a record every time it's fetched from the database has a significant smell to it, and it's hard to imagine a scenario in which the number of time's it's been fetched would be a useful metric.

Answer (score 1):

A new factory to override the default factory would be the correct way to do this.

An example:

```
class Apple < ActiveRecord::Base
  # ...
  def self.delicious
    # increase count or other complex operations here
    where(:name => "Delicious").first
  end
  # ...
end
```

In this case, `where` is the default factory.

With this, you can just call `Apple.delicious` and get done with.

Comment: I'd argue against the use of `.first` here, since it forces a query. But I think it is out scope for this question.